# Vectorizing which operation across the rows of a matrix

Tags: r, vectorization

I would like to vectorize (`apply`) a `which` operation on matrix `X` as illustrated by the following `for` loop having as result the vector `ind`:

```
X   = matrix( 1:20, 4, 5 )
V   = sample( 1:20, 4 )
ind = numeric()
for( i in 1:nrow(X) ) ind[i] = max( c(0, which(X[i,] < V[i]) ))
```

The operation returns in `ind` for each row in `X` the index of the element with the highest value smaller than the value indicated by the `X`-row-corresponding element of `V`.

The operation `max` maps the vector of all eligible indices to a scalar. Alternatively I would by happy with an operation returning e.g. a `list` of all indices (to which I can `lapply` `max`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your matrix has increasing values like the example you shared (which of course I doubt), but If it does you can simply do,

```
rowSums(X < V)
#[1] 4 3 4 0
```

However, If this is not the case, then a simple `apply` will suffice, i.e.

```
apply(X < V, 1, function(i)max(which(i)))
#[1]    4    3    4 -Inf
```

Remember that all mathematical operations are vectorized, so `<` is vectorized

You can replace `-Inf` as per usual

Answer (score 3):

```
apply(
    (X < V) * X
    , 1
    , which.max
)
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output. - FYI, **NOT** my downvote

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple lapply example

```
X   = matrix( 1:20, 4, 5 )
V   = sample( 1:20, 4 )
ind = numeric()
for( i in 1:nrow(X) ) ind[i] = max( c(0, which(X[i,] < V[i]) ))

mymax = function(matrix, sample) {
    whichlist = which(matrix < sample)
    max(0, whichlist)
}
ind2 = unlist(lapply(1:nrow(X), function(r) mymax(X[r,], V[r])))

identical(ind, ind2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer where you first `sweep` the vector `V` across each row of `X` and then you use apply to determine the maximum `TRUE` element of each row.

```
set.seed(14)
X   = matrix( 1:20, 4, 5 )
V   = sample( 1:20, 4 )
ind1 = numeric()
for( i in 1:nrow(X) ) ind1[i] =  max(c(0, which(X[i,] < V[i]) ))



ind2 <- apply(
  sweep(X, 1, V, "<"),
  1,
  function(x){
    max(
    which(
      x,
      arr.ind = TRUE)
    )
  }
)


> ind1
[1] 2 5 2 4
> ind2
[1] 2 5 2 4
```